# How do I debug C++ runtime errors on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

I am new to C++ development and using Mac. I am looking for a way to debug the runtime errors somehow. I am writing my code in Xcode, but would be open to switching to another IDE, like CLion, if it had that feature.

Comment: What sort of "runtime errors"? What sort of "somehow" debugging? You need to be much more specific about what you want to do and why you can't do it on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ compilation on OSX is done through LLVM toolchain with Clang compiler. This includes `lldb`, which is a powerful debugger readily available on Xcode to do whatever you need.

Take a look here: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/12/13/xcode-lldb-tutorial/

It's related to Objective-C development but the procedure is absolutely the same.